# How to Flag Yes If few column Present in the tables in sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario which I need to check all tables in the database and identify few columns present in the tables or not. And I need to flag yes if it is presented.

Now I got the result like this

```
Table   Column      CreatedDate EditedDate  Date
Table1  CreatedDate Yes         NULL        NULL
Table1  Date        NULL        NULL        Yes
Table1  EditedDate  NULL        Yes         NULL
Table2  CreatedDate Yes         NULL        NULL
Table2  Date        NULL        NULL        Yes
Table2  EditedDate  NULL        Yes         NULL
Table3  CreatedDate Yes         NULL        NULL
Table3  Date        NULL        NULL        NULL
Table3  EditedDate  NULL        Yes         NULL
```

The query which I used is:

```
SELECT
    tables.name AS TableName,


  case 
  when sys.columns.name ='CreatedDate' then 'Yes'

  end as CreatedDateCheck,

  Case

   when sys.columns.name ='EditedDate' then 'Yes'
  end as EditedDateCheck,

    Case

   when sys.columns.name ='Date' then 'Yes'
  end as EditedDateCheck

FROM
  sys.columns
JOIN sys.tables ON
  sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
WHERE
  sys.columns.name like '%Date'"
```

but I have to show the result like this:

```
    Table       CreatedDate EditedDate  Date
    Table1      Yes         Yes         Yes
    Table2      Yes         NULL        Yes
    Table3      Yes         Yes         NULL
```

Comment: This is a SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same with PIVOT and dynamic SQL. However the simple way is to use aggregate functions:

```
USE master

SELECT t.name  
, MAX(CASE WHEN c.name = 'dbid' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS dbid
, MAX(CASE WHEN c.name = 'status' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS status
, MAX(CASE WHEN c.name = 'xdttm_ins' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS xdttm_ins
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
GROUP BY T.name
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how max is used here

Comment: for all columns other than chosen one it will return No. N comes before Y so N < Y